# keeping multiple checkboxes checked in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes within a foreach loop and I need to keep the selected checkboxes checked after the form submission. The code is as below. Please help.

```
     <? $i=0;
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
          foreach($row=$val)
          {
            $id="chkbox".$i;
      ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" onclick ="func()" id="<?echo   $id;">? value="<?echo $val \n;?>" <? echo "$val";?>
```

Now where and how to include the checked property of the boxes..

Comment: Can you paste your while loop here ? Also, are you sure that  you need to run `foreach` inside this `while` ?

Comment: The code is wrong. You are trying to convert $val from array to string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `foreach` loop here

This can be done for checking multiple **checkbox** checked

```
  <?php
    $i=0;
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $checked = "";
        if($row['database_column_name']=$val){
            $checked = "checked";
        }
        echo '
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" onclick ="func()" id="'.$id.'" value="'.$val.'" '.$checked.'>'.
          $val
         .'
        ';
    }
    ?>
```

Works for me.

Comment: Since he fetch array as associative, i guess the code should be like `if($row['database_column_name'] = $val){
            $checked = "checked";
}`

Comment: @Meenesh Jain I need foreach loop to get the values from the array.. Sorry for the typo, I am using foreach($row as $val) and then retrieving the values one by one and inserting checkboxes for each.